# Angular2 RouteParams not getting parameter

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am having an issue with getting parameter from a route in Angular2. In `app.component.ts` I am defining `@RouterConfig`:

```
@RouteConfig([
...
{ path: '/companies', component: CompaniesListComponent, name: 'Companies' },
{ path: '/events/:nameId', component: EventsListComponent, name: 'Events'}
])
```

Inside of `CompaniesListComponent`'s template I am having the following `[routerLink]`:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/Events', { 'nameId': company.nameId }]" class="btn btn-success col-md-offset-4">Show Events</a>
```

When I hover over the link above it clearly shows me that `company.nameId` is set correctly and the url looks like: `/events/cssmelbourne`, where `cssmelbourne` is `nameId`. When I am clicking the link `EventsListComponent` is not loading due to `nameId is not defined`. I am trying to get `nameId` parameter in the following way:

```
nameId: string = "";
constructor(private routeParams: RouteParams, private http: Http) {
  this.nameId = routeParams.get('nameId');
}
```

I have also tried to use `this.nameId = routeParams.params['nameId'];` but no success.

Comment: can you see the nameId in browser url block After router link on 'Show  Events'

Comment: When I hover over I see `nameId` and in console too.

Comment: I mean the value that is substituted for `nameId`, say, `cssmelbourne`

Comment: So, this seems right. Seems like the main issue happens upon retrieval. I am not sure about the correctness of my architecture: I have a link inside of `CompaniesListComponent`, so child component has a link that is handled by parent `@RouteConfig`. Not sure whether it is related, just a doubt.

Comment: Just try this link [routerLink]="['/Events', { 'nameId': 'Foo' }]" lets see whats happens

Comment: Same thing. I see `Foo` in `URL` of the link, but when clicking on it same thing happens

Comment: dont seems any problem in this. Add some more details like may be Image file of browser error Are you updated with angular 2 rc-3 . because i tried the same example but it work with me

Comment: yes, it is angular 2 rc-3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115675/discussion-between-mayur-and-nikita-vlasenko).

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately the error was happening inside `EventsListComponent`'s `console.log` statement. I forgot to put `this.` before the variable. So, before it was the following:

```
export class EventsListComponent {
nameId: string = "";
  constructor(private routeParams: RouteParams, private http: Http) {
    this.nameId = routeParams.params['nameId'];
    console.log("nameId: " + nameId);
  }
}
```

But it should be:

```
export class EventsListComponent {
nameId: string = "";
  constructor(private routeParams: RouteParams, private http: Http) {
    this.nameId = routeParams.params['nameId'];
    console.log("nameId: " + this.nameId);
  }
}
```